# Create a dropdownList of checkboxes with EPPLUS Core in Asp Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I managed to add a dropdown populated with values in an other sheet, but it allows me to only select one value.

I have a case I need to select more than one value using DataValidation in EPPLUS.

How could I add for exemple a list of checkboxes instead of a simple dropdown ?

I tried

```
var validationCell = sheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation("A1");
validationCell.Formula.Values.Add("a");
validationCell.Formula.Values.Add("b");
validationCell.Formula.Values.Add("c");
```

But I only can select one checkbox, I need to select multiple to have multiple values in an array for example.

So is there any way to make this dropdown of checkboxes to allow me to choose multiple values ?

I've found a tutorial to create it directly in Excel :
[Tuto](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbalistboxcreate.html)

Is it possible to do the same thing with EPPLUS Core?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by inserting VBA Code:

see how to do it in [here](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/) , using EPPlus you can insert VBA code using something like:

```
package.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
worksheet.CodeModule.Code = code;
```

This following code did the trick:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("D:\\b.xlsm")))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("11");
            var validationCell = worksheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation("A1");
            validationCell.Formula.Values.Add("a");
            validationCell.Formula.Values.Add("b");
            validationCell.Formula.Values.Add("c");

            string code = "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)\n" +
"Dim Oldvalue As String\n" +
"Dim Newvalue As String\n" +
"Application.EnableEvents = True\n" +
"On Error GoTo Exitsub\n" +
"If Target.Address = \"$A$1\" Then\n" +
 " If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then\n" +
  "  GoTo Exitsub\n" +
  "Else: If Target.Value = \"\" Then GoTo Exitsub Else\n" +
   " Application.EnableEvents = False\n" +
    "Newvalue = Target.Value\n" +
    "Application.Undo\n" +
    "Oldvalue = Target.Value\n" +
    "  If Oldvalue = \"\" Then\n" +
     "   Target.Value = Newvalue\n" +
      "Else\n" +
       " If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then\n" +
        "    Target.Value = Oldvalue & \", \" & Newvalue\n" +
      "Else: \n" +
       "         Target.Value = Oldvalue\n" +
      "End If\n" +
    "End If\n" +
  "End If\n" +
 "End If\n" +
"Application.EnableEvents = True\n" +
"Exitsub: \n" +
 "  Application.EnableEvents = True\n" +
"End Sub";

            package.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
            worksheet.CodeModule.Code = code;
            package.Save();
        }
```

Comment: yes but my problem is how can I delete items from the list ? When I delete an select item the validation is broken. That's why I'd like to have a liste of checkboxes inside the dropdown

Comment: what do you mean by delete a selected item? can you please explain?

Comment: for exemple I select 3 items : One, two, three
If I select ",three" and erase it to only let "One, two" I have a validation error because the value "One, two " isn't in the values list

Comment: But I think it's ok, the user will delete the cell values and select items he needs again. ^^ Thanks you